# Valid position in array

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexoutofrangeexception

```
         else:

              res = (numbers.index(str_pos[1:]), letters.index(str_pos[0]))
        return res

def is_in_board(n,pos):
         letters = [chr(x + ord('a')) for x in range(n)]
         numbers = [str(x) for x in range(1, n + 1)]
         numbers.reverse()
         pos = ''.join([letters[pos[1]], numbers[pos[0]]])
         if extract_pos(n,pos) is not None:
               return True
         else:
               return False
```

How can I return False when the list (pos) index is out of range ?[board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Xcl.png)

Answer (score 0):

At the first line of the function `extract_pos` function you know all that you need:

- The size of the plate: `n x n`
- The desired indexes: `str_pos`

So I would do something like this at the first line of the `extract_pos` function:

```
if int(str_pos[0]) >= n or int(str_pos[1]) >= n or int(str_pos[0]) < 0 or int(str_pos[1]) < 0 :
    return 'Out of index'
```

Then you have to check that return value in the `is_in_board` function:

```
extract_pos_return_value = extract_pos(n,pos)
if extract_pos_return_value is not None and extract_pos_return_value is not 'Out of index':
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Full Code:

```
def extract_pos(n, str_pos):
        if int(str_pos[0]) >= n or int(str_pos[1]) >= n or int(str_pos[0]) < 0 or int(str_pos[1]) < 0 :
              return 'Out of index'
        letters = [chr(x + ord('a')) for x in range(n)]
        numbers = [str(x) for x in range(1,n+1)]
        numbers.reverse()


         if len(str_pos) < 2 or str_pos[0] not in letters or str_pos[1] not in numbers:
              res = None

         else:

              res = (numbers.index(str_pos[1:]), letters.index(str_pos[0]))
        return res

def is_in_board(n,pos):
         letters = [chr(x + ord('a')) for x in range(n)]
         numbers = [str(x) for x in range(1, n + 1)]
         numbers.reverse()
         pos = ''.join([letters[pos[1]], numbers[pos[0]]])
         extract_pos_return_value = extract_pos(n,pos)
         if extract_pos_return_value is not None and extract_pos_return_value is not 'Out of index':
              return True
         else:
              return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to show you a simpler solution.

First, you do not need to construct lists for letters and for numbers, it is much easier to check the parameter.

Then in your `is_in_board` function you have not handled your `pos` parameter correctly.

Please check this solution:

```
def extract_pos(n, str_pos):
        if 1<=ord(str_pos[0])-ord('a')<=n and 1<=ord(str_pos[1])-ord('0')<=n:
            return n-int(str_pos[1]), (ord(str_pos[0])-ord('a'))
        else:
            return None
            
def is_in_board(n, pos):
         xpos = extract_pos(n,chr(pos[1]+ord('a'))+chr(8-pos[0]+ord('0')))
         if xpos != None:
             x, y = xpos
             if 0<=x<n and 0<=y<n:
               return True
         return False
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work because the output for example extract_pos(7,b2) must return (5,1)

Comment: OK, I've changed the example code.

Comment: Thank's again, but there is a problem on is_in_board.
in extract_pos
    if 1 <= ord(str_pos[0]) - ord('a') <= n and 1 <= ord(str_pos[1]) - ord('0') <= n:
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Traceback (most recent call last):
in is_in_board
    xpos = extract_pos(n, pos)

print(is_in_board(7,(0,5))) must be return True
print(is_in_board(7,(1,7))) must be return False

Thanks for help:)

Comment: What was exactly the function call? It works for me e.g. using `is_in_board(7,'b2')`

Comment: Unfortunately, pos must be Tuple[int, int]

For extract_pos Position a7 should match the pair of indices (0, 0) but it call out None

Comment: @john200 I do not know what you need. I wrote a simple example what you should be able to easily customize. OK, I've updated the example code. Hope it does what you want.